# State of array is not updated in ComponentDidMount

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, components

I have a weird situation, where I have an array as a state:
`this.state = { ActivityItem: []}` and I am pushing values to it from library that calls an API like this:

```
   getDataFromKit(dateFrom) {


                Kit.getSamples(stepCountSample, (err, results) => { //api call
                if (err) {
                    return;
                }
                const newData = results.map(item => { return { ...item, name: 'itemAmount' } });
                this.setState({ d: [...this.state.ActivityItem, ...newData] })

            })
```

Then, I call this method from ComponentDidMount() for array to be loaded

```
  componentDidMount() {
     this.getDataFromHealthKit(ONEDAYINTERVAL);
    console.log("values are", this.state.ActivityItem)
}
```

Now, the weirdest part: somehow the array is empty in ComponentDidMount, but when I display elements of Array in return of render() function it displays all the values that were added correctly. How is that possible and how I might fix that?

Answer (score 0):

setState is asynchronous in nature. Therefore, logging the state just immediately after setting it can give this behaviour but if set properly, it will display the required content which is happening in your case. Also componentDidMount is called only once in the beginning so you can check for logs in componentDidUpdate method.

Answer (score 0):

State updates are async in nature. If you want to print the state soon after setting your state in class component, then pass a function to the 2nd argument of `setState`.

**Like this**

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.getDataFromHealthKit(ONEDAYINTERVAL);
  // remove console.log   
}
...


getDataFromKit(dateFrom) {
    ...
   this.setState({ ActivityItem: [...this.state.ActivityItem, ...newData] }), () => {
    console.log("values are", this.state.ActivityItem) //<---- 
   }
})
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `prevstate` while updating the state value. React setState is an asynchronous update and does batch updating. Using `prevState` makes sure that the state value is updated before calculating new state value.

```
getDataFromKit(dateFrom) {
    let stepCountSample = {
      startDate: dateFrom.toISOString(),
      type: "Type1"
    };

    Kit.getSamples(stepCountSample, (err, results) => {
      //api call
      if (err) {
        return;
      }
      const newData = results.map(item => {
        return { ...item, name: "itemAmount" };
      });
      this.setState(prevState => {
        ActivityItem: [...prevState.ActivityItem, ...newData];
      });
    });
  }
```

[DOCUMENTATION](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) would help understand the concept

Also, `console.log` would directly not give the updated state, since state updates are batched. You can use a callback method to setState function. The callback will run only after successfull updation of state value